# Iterate through grouped rows to get different pair combinations

Tags: r, dplyr, iteration

Having the following table:

```
read.table(text = "route origin dest seq
    1   a b 1
    1   b c 2
    1   c d 3
    1   d e 4
    2   f g 1
    2   g h 2
    2   h i 3", header = TRUE)
```

I'm trying to find a way of going through each row, grouped by route, and iterate every potential combination of origin destination pairs, taking into account the seq variable and the route as mentioned.

The output should look something like this:

```
  origin   dest
    a       b 
    a       c 
    a       d 
    a       e 
    b       c
    b       d
  (...)   (...)
```

The idea behind this is that a train e.g route 1, goes from a to e. However, I want to list every single possibility of train pairs with that. I tried with igraph but unsuccessfully.
Any ideas with dplyr or so?

Comment: Based on your input, how many rows would you expect in the expected output

Comment: Try `library(tidyverse); expand(df1, route, origin, dest)`

Comment: @akrun well I expect 9 for route 1. So a combination of origin and a destination which is just always the following row's destination.
The thing with the `expand` is that it goes until the end of the table and doesn't take into account the groups for some strange reason.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira , are you sure? I think its 10 for route 1?

Comment: @PKumar you're right it's 10. I'm just a bit sleep deprived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%    #convert factor variable to character
  group_by(route) %>%
  expand(origin = paste(origin, seq, sep = "_"), dest = paste(dest, seq, sep = "_")) %>%    #all possible combination of origin & destination grouped by route
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(strsplit(origin, split = "_")[[1]][1] != strsplit(dest, split = "_")[[1]][1] & 
           strsplit(origin, split = "_")[[1]][2] <= strsplit(dest, split = "_")[[1]][2]) %>%
  mutate(origin = gsub("_.*$", "", origin),
         dest   = gsub("_.*$", "", dest))
```

**Output is:**

```
   route origin dest 
 1     1 a      b    
 2     1 a      c    
 3     1 a      d    
 4     1 a      e    
 5     1 b      c    
...
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(route = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), origin = structure(1:7, .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h"), class = "factor"), dest = structure(1:7, .Label = c("b", 
"c", "d", "e", "g", "h", "i"), class = "factor"), seq = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

#  route origin dest seq
#1     1      a    b   1
#2     1      b    c   2
#3     1      c    d   3
#4     1      d    e   4
#5     2      f    g   1
#6     2      g    h   2
#7     2      h    i   3
```